# sql server alwayson secondary sync database delay

Tags: sql-server, alwayson

I have a sqlserver 2016 always-on with one primary and one secondary database. However I got nothing when I query the secondary database right after I get confirmation from primary database that insert is done. 
So I think this is because primary db confirm the transaction after log received at secondary db, however secondary database takes some time to write record into db after it received the log from primary db. 
So there are definitely some delay between primary and secondary db, question is how can I query secondary db instantly after I get confirmation from primary db?

Comment: anyone can help??  I learn about pear-to-pear replication, however, document still said that it is still problematic for latest change to be seen immediately.

Comment: did I come to the wrong place? why nobody answer this?

Comment: pear to pear or peer-to-peer ? also yes it always takes time to replicate data from primary node to secondary so if you're executing write query (which will go to primary) now these changes will take some time to reflect in secondary replica's depending on various factors such as volume of data, network bandwidth etc.